# \if leqno or reqno: command to check whether left or right eq. Numbers were set

Tags: macros, horizontal-alignment, equations, numbering

I am defining my own command and need to check, which mode the user has set, whether reqno or leqno. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3):

If `amsmath` is used then

```
\iftagsleft@
```

is true or not.

For `article` and other classes, you need to check the definition of `\@eqnnum`
or you could use

```
\@ifl@aded{clo}{leqno}{yes}{no}
```

Comment: Okay I will try this.

Comment: The first option worked (I have not tried the second suggestion). Thanks!